# Window.document not updated

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I open a new tab in the browser with `const w = window.open('www.example.com');` and I get the DOM with `let d = w.document;` Then I go to another webpage with an click-event: `d.querySelector('a').click()`; The new webpage opens, in the same window, and I want to grap the DOM of the just openend page by running `d = w.document` again. And this is the point where I get stuck.

I aspect the DOM of the currently openend window, but instead I get the DOM of the previous window back. When `console.log(w)` (in the .js itself not in the console), with the new webpage open, I get the `window` object of the current page and the `window.document` matches the DOM of the openend page. But as I said in reality I get the DOM of the previous page back when I run `d = w.document` on the new page.

The following code is the whole function I use. Sidenote: I didn't(/couldn't) use `window.document.onload` fom I reason I don't understand, but It seems I can't attach an function to the window onload event. Also to make things clear my code is inside of a ES6 Class so I didn't use the `const`as in the example.

**The Problem**:
When I run the `getDOM` method on the new openend webpage it returns the DOM of the previous page.

```
 async foo() {
    await this.getDOM()
    .then(w => this.d = w.document);

    const x = this.d.querySelector('button.x');
    console.log(send); //null
}

getDOM () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.w.document.readyState === 'complete') {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(this.w);
            }
        }, 500);    
    });
}
```

I hope someone can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `this.w` in the `getDOM` function is pointing to the correct window? Where is `this.w` coming from?

Comment: @xander this.w is initialised in the class constructor, this.w = window.open('www.example.com'), and yes its pointing to the right window. but I when I try to grap the DOM of the new page I get the DOM of the previous page